# VS code moves the cursor to start of next line when pressing enter key

Tags: visual-studio-code

Instead of respecting the current block's indentation level, the cursor moves to the start of the new line when pressing the enter key.

```
          {
             "name": "foo",
|
          }
```

The cursor should jump to the same level as the `name` key.

This happens even with the empty curly brackets.

```
          {|}
```

Hit `enter`

```
          {
|}
```

There doesn't seem to be a setting that can be set so the cursor only jumps to the current indentation level.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the default value of Editor:auto.indent was "full", but I still experienced the issue.
To fix, I needed to **re-save** Settings (after changing the option twice) to make it work in C#.

[Option illustration in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7uzq.png)

Answer (score 2):

I found that `editor.language.brackets` was set to [] in Settings.json. Remove it, and should work as expected.

Comment: +1
More details on that here
https://dev.to/killshot13/configuring-vscode-colorized-brackets-5733

Answer (score 1):

I kind of fixed this issue by setting the Editor:auto.indent to "full".

Answer (score 1):

This issue can also happen if you have `"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"`. Saving the file moves your cursor at the beginning of the line, if line is empty.

Answer (score 1):

It can also happen if you're using the `yapf` extension for formatting. Make sure you have `"editor.formatOnType": false`.

```
"[python]": {
"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.defaultFormatter": "eeyore.yapf",
"editor.formatOnType": false
```

}